# Using tuples inside iterator blocks and async blocks

Tags: c#, .net, optimization, iterator, async-await

Both [iterators](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dscyy5s0.aspx) and [async methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443.aspx) create a state machine for keeping the state between yield/await operations and every *local* in your method becomes a *field* in that instance of the state machine type.

In [this talk](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/BUILD/BUILD2011/TOOL-829T), Stephen Toub talks about having less local variables in the bodies of *async methods* is a valid (no micro) optimization if you have lots of await calls. (i.e. if you're awaiting in a loop)

So in this case, I wonder the performance difference between having 7 locals and having one local which is a `Tuple<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7>` .

Obviously, it does nothing but to complicate things if there is only one *yield* in the iterator or only one *await* in the async method but when it comes to thousands or more, do you think using tuples (or any other type that will wrap your fields) do any good?

Or would that be just another micro-optimization attempt that accomplishes nothing or too less to use?

**Edit:** Now that I thought it again, it would already be *implemented that way* if it would do any good, I suppose. Nonetheless, I'm still curious about it.

Comment: Have you tried measuring this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have thousands of await/yield, then something is already very wrong. It should also be noted that the two have different implementations. However, changing to a tuple isn't adding anything useful, IMO. You are still storing (as state) a single reference in either case, no matter whether that reference is:

- the iterator instance
- a captured-variable context
- a tuple
- a captured-variable context *to* a tuple

But by using a tuple you guarantee you need a new instance any time you need to mutate a variable.

Tulle *can* be more interesting when implementing async manually (things like ContinueWith), but I really don't think it is worth it when using the compiler to provide the implementation.

Comment: Wasn't sure whether I should have deleted the question when I found out the "duh?" answer: How can initializing a class with seven fields be an optimization to make the state machine have those fields? Thank you and +1 for stating it :)

Comment: By the way, why should having thousands of yields mean that something is wrong? What if I call Enumerable.Where for a collection that has thousands of items?

Comment: @safak if you mean "in a loop", then fine - no problem! If, however, you mean you have a method with a thousand uses of the "yield" or "await" keywords, then that method seems to be doing too much